# Tensorflow how to produce mask with first few rows are 1, the rest are 0

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create mask matrix, are there any function like this in Tensorflow,

```
function(true_line=2, row_length=5, column_length=3)
```

Output:

```
True True True
True True True
False False False
False False False
False False False
```

The first `true_line` are filled with `True`, and the column length is `3`, the total row length is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.stack to create above mask matrix.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([True, True,True])
b = tf.constant([True, True,True])
c = tf.constant([False, False,False])
d = tf.constant([False, False,False])
e = tf.constant([False, False,False])
f = tf.constant([False, False,False])
filter = tf.stack([a, b, c,d, e, f])
print(filter)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]], shape=(6, 3), dtype=bool)
```

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack